# If A is a nonempty set, prove that there does not exist a set G of all functions whose domain is A

Tags: functions, set-theory

I am taking an Axiomatic Set Theory course at my university and this is one of the questions I got wrong in my first exam. As I study for the final I want to understand my mistakes.

For some background, we prove set existence by the Subset Axiom and use Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory in the course.

The question in full is " Prove: If A is a nonempty set, then there does not exist a set G such that the members of G are exactly all the functions whose domain is A. Hint: For every set x, construct a function f:A->{x}"

My guess here is to show that range(f) is the set of all sets which doesn't exist.. does this seem right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite, since the range of $f$ is just $\{x\},$ which is a set.

What we are actually doing is constructing a function between the universe of sets and the collection $\mathcal C_A$ of all functions with domain $A$ by letting $F(x)=c_x$ where $c_x$ is the constant function on $A$ with value $x$ (this is the "$f$" they were suggesting).

$F$ is an injection of the universe into $\mathcal C_A,$ so $\mathcal C_A$ is not a set: for any set $X$, the restriction of $F$ to $X$ is an injection $X\to \mathcal C_A,$ so if it were a set it would have a cardinality larger than any other set, which is impossible by Cantor's theorem.

Alternatively, closer to what you suggested, you can look at the *union of the ranges* of all the functions in $\mathcal C_A,$ which would be a set if $\mathcal C_A$ were (by replacement, amongst other things). And then observe that since $c_x\in \mathcal C_A$ for all $x\in V,$ that this union is all of $V.$

**edit**

Here is a somewhat more explicit and careful version of the last paragraph. Let $A$ be any nonempty set and assume $C_A$ is a set such that $f\in C_A$ if and only if $f$ is a function with domain $A.$ Then let $Z = \cup\{\operatorname{ran}(f): f\in C_A\}$ which exists (i.e. is a set) by union and replacement. Now let $x$ be any set. Since $A$ is nonempty, there is a function $f\in C_A$ that is just the constant function with value $x,$ so $x\in \operatorname{ran}(f)$ and hence $x\in Z.$ Thus $Z$ contains all sets, from which we can derive a well known contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the response and after reading up on von Neuman-Bernays alternative used in the appendix of our textbook I vaguely understand your approach. Do you have an alternative without using collections of sets (=> functions)?

Comment: I ask because my professor is also very strict with our derivations and I'm sure I would lose points by using collections.

Comment: @AlexLaShell Does the approach in the last paragraph not work on those grounds? (I agree the language of the first argument I gave is a bit NBG-y.)

Comment: My fault, I can assume that the "collection of all functions" as you denote is a set and use contradiction as you state in the last paragraph. Now that I know this is not a set, I cannot derive the set of all functions from this (by using the subset axiom), correct?

Comment: @AlexLaShell I added a more explicit argument.  Yes, that's right... it is a proof by contradiction starting with the assumption that there is a set whose elements are exactly the functions with domain $A.$ I'm not sure what you mean by your second question. The class of all functions isn't a subclass of $C_A,$ it is the other way around.

Comment: Your edit clarified this perfectly, thank you very much.